# Consumo de Web Service no padrão SOAP com envio de XML como parâmetro em PHP

Tags: php, web-service, xml, soap

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de integração entre a prefeitura da minha cidade e um sistema para uma empresa, para otimização da geração de NFS-e. Consiste em utilizar o Web Service da prefeitura para enviar, utilizando SOAP, arquivos XML para serem validados. Ou seja, o parâmetro passado será um arquivo XML.

Como nunca criei esse tipo de aplicação, estou com dúvida quanto a como fazer isso. Por exemplo:

Como utilizo os serviços disponibilizados (http://grphml.santacruz.rs.gov.br/thema-nfse-hml/) e faço a comunicação SOAP em PHP? Supondo que eu tenha o arquivo XML pronto e estruturado corretamente, como passo ele como parâmetro para os serviços do Web Service?

Não quero a solução de nada, somente dicas e exemplos que possam me ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, na minha opinião este é um tópico bem complexo, se tratando de NFS-e é bem provável que vale a pena você usar uma API/biblioteca já pronta criada por outras pessoas, ou seja, não tente fazer tudo do zero...

*Como utilizo os serviços disponibilizados (http://grphml.santacruz.rs.gov.br/thema-nfse-hml/) e faço a comunicação SOAP em PHP?* ==> Usando as funções do cURL(), veja http://php.net/curl

Depois como sugestão veja os esforços já existentes da comunidade NFePHP, https://github.com/nfephp-org/sped-nfe (é a NF-e nacional mas tem iniciativas de NFS-e também).

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado pelas referências Fernando.